# How can I efficiently find lists of chance correspondences?

Tags: resource-request, self-learning, language-comparison

Where can I find such compilations or lists systematically?

- [This Japanese-English example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K01KM.jpg) is from
  John McWhorter [PhD Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter)'s [*The Power of Babel* (2003)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/006052085X), pp. 226-227.
- I'm aware of [r/FalseFriends](https://old.reddit.com/r/FalseFriends/top/).

I don't specify which L2 languages, as I'm interested in too many. My L1s are English and French.